# Composer is downloading all files in the php folder rather than in my project root folder?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I was learning my first video of how to check out and make a transaction.

I have installed composer in the xampp/php/ directory. Now when I ran this query
'composer require stripe/stripe-php'
it created all the files like vendor,composer.json and composer.lock in the php folder. How to make it download them all in the root folder of my project?

sorry for my bad English but I hope you get my point.

Comment: Composer donwloads those files in the folder you're in when you're using it, so you need to make composer globally available, like putting it in `/usr/local/bin/` on nix and osx or add the composer path to your PATH-variable. Then you go to the folder where you're project is and run `composer require xxx/xxx`

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: yes I did and it worked. Thank you. You saved my life<3